# How do I get the path of a file

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, path, directory

I'm new on this, and I get really stuck
Can somebody tell me please how to get the path of a file
Im actually making a conection with sqlite but I want to search the .db file in all C disk

here the code

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory) + "\\database.db");
```

But this just search the file in the project folder and I want to search the .db file in all C disk

Thanks in advice

Comment: Where exactly your db file located? Is it anywhere in c drive or anywhere inside subdirectories of c drive?

Comment: Opening some random file does not make sense. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?